# Encoding variable-length quanties for MIDI

Tags: c#, algorithm, bitwise, audio

I was reading about the [MIDI spec](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~music/cmsip/readings/Standard-MIDI-file-format-updated.pdf) and I challenged myself to implement a function to convert an int32 to a variable length quantity `uint32`.

I didn't look it up or anything so there might be a way more efficient or tricky way to get the same result, but as far as doing what I set out to accomplish the following code works.

I'm interested to know if anyone can significantly simplify or improve the algorithm that does the conversion, `public static uint CalculateEncodedQuantity(int q)`.

I included the whole thing in case anyone wanted to paste it in to VS.

**Specification**:
[image]

**Tests**:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace VariableLengthRepresentation.Test
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(0u, new VariableLengthQuantity(0).EncodedQuantity);
            Assert.AreEqual(0x40u, new VariableLengthQuantity(0x40).EncodedQuantity);
            Assert.AreEqual(0x7fu, new VariableLengthQuantity(0x7f).EncodedQuantity);

            //  input:           1000 0000
            // output: 1000 0001 0000 0000
            Assert.AreEqual(0x8100u, new VariableLengthQuantity(0x80).EncodedQuantity);

            //  input: 0010 0000 0000 0000
            // output: 1100 0000 0000 0000
            Assert.AreEqual(0xc000u, new VariableLengthQuantity(0x2000).EncodedQuantity);

            Assert.AreEqual(0xff7fu, new VariableLengthQuantity(0x3fff).EncodedQuantity);
            Assert.AreEqual(0x818000u, new VariableLengthQuantity(0x4000).EncodedQuantity);
            Assert.AreEqual(0xc08000u, new VariableLengthQuantity(0x100000).EncodedQuantity);
            Assert.AreEqual(0xffff7fu, new VariableLengthQuantity(0x1fffff).EncodedQuantity);
            Assert.AreEqual(0x81808000u, new VariableLengthQuantity(0x200000).EncodedQuantity);
            Assert.AreEqual(0xc0808000u, new VariableLengthQuantity(0x8000000).EncodedQuantity);
            Assert.AreEqual(0xffffff7fu, new VariableLengthQuantity(0xfffffff).EncodedQuantity);
        }
    }
}
```

**Implementation**:

```
using System;

namespace VariableLengthRepresentation
{
    public struct VariableLengthQuantity
    {
        public VariableLengthQuantity(int quantity)
        {
            Quantity = quantity;
            EncodedQuantity = CalculateEncodedQuantity(quantity);
        }

        public static uint CalculateEncodedQuantity(int q)
        {
            if (q > 0x0fffffff)
            {
                throw new Exception("Variable length quantity cannot exceed 0x0fffffff.");
            }

            uint n = (uint)q;

            if (n < 128)
                return n;

            var result = new byte[4];

            for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                result[i] = (byte)(n & 0x7f);

                if(i < 3)
                    result[i] |= 0x80;

                n >>= 7;

                if (n < 1)
                    break;
            }

            if(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
                Array.Reverse(result);

            return BitConverter.ToUInt32(result, 0);
        }

        public int Quantity { get; private set; }
        public uint EncodedQuantity { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If an argument doesn't fit in the desired range an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` should be thrown instead of an `Exception`.

---

> ```
>     for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
>     {
>         result[i] = (byte)(n & 0x7f);
>
>         if(i < 3)
>             result[i] |= 0x80;
>
>         n >>= 7;
>
>         if (n < 1)
>             break;
>     }
> ```

This can be rewritten to remove the `if(i < 3)` by starting the loop at `2`. The check `if (n < 1)` can be placed in the loop condition like

```
result[3] = (byte)(n & 0x7f);
n >>= 7;  

for (int i = 2; (i >= 0) || (n > 0); i--)
{
    result[i] = ((byte)(n & 0x7f)) | 0x80;
    n >>= 7;
}
```

---

You have some magic numbers in your code. The values `0x0fffffff`, `128`, `0x7f`, `0x80` and `7` should be extracted to descriptive named constants.

---

Also there isn't explicitly written anything in any guidelines about braces `{}` for single instruction `if` statements I would encourage you to always use them to make your code less error prone.

---

You shouldn't shorten variables / parameter names. It is easier to read if the passed in parameter is named `quantity` instead of `q`.

---

The fact that you are taking care about the `Endianess` of the system should be stated in a xml documentation.